# Cannot find symbol in java, ADT card application

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been trying to create a card application to complete a perfect shuffle. I am being met with the error above within this segment of code.

```
  public class Deck {


private List<Card> cards;


private int size;//number of cards in deck


public Deck(String[] faces, String[] suits, int[] values){
   cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
   for(String suit: suits) 
       for(int value = 0; value < values.length; value++){
           Card a = new Card(faces[face], suit, values[face]);
           cards.add(a);
       }
   size = cards.size();

}//ends deck
```

More specifically this line, in reference to the face variable.

```
               Card a = new Card(faces[face], suit, values[face]);
```

I have created the variable face in another class i have stored in the application called Card.

```
public class Card {


private String suit;


private String face;


private int value;



public Card(String cardFace, String cardSuit, int cardValue){
    face = cardFace;
    suit = cardSuit;
    value = cardValue;
}//ends Card

public String suit(){

return suit;
}//ends suit

public String face(){

return face;
}//ends face
```

Im sure this is an easy fix just looking a point in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `faces[face]` when face is a String? use the for loop index value like `faces[value]`

Comment: Returning an error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 52, Size: 52 now, any idea?

Comment: Sounds like somewhere else in the code has an issue where you go off by one in an array of Cards. We can't see your main method as it stands right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
for(int value = 0; value < values.length; value++){
   Card a = new Card(faces[face], suit, values[face]);
   cards.add(a);
}
```

with

```
for(int value = 0; value < values.length && value < faces.length; value++){
   Card a = new Card(faces[value], suit, values[value]);
   cards.add(a);
}
```

The following issues have been addressed in the code given above:

1. Using the loop counter, `value` as the index value.
2. Checking the length of both, `values` and `faces` arrays because the values from each of these arrays are being accessed using the loop counter, `value`.

Comment: Returning an error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 52, Size: 52 now, any idea?

Comment: The error doesn't look like it is in that same for loop, sounds like they have issues in the main method accessing index 52 of cards list

Comment: Found the solution, was to do with my deal method as i had size --; after cards.get.size() instead of before, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Card a = new Card(faces[face], suit, values[face]);
```

**face** is not defined in faces[**face**] & values[**face**]